# Script output is incorrect

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, queue

I have written a script that uses ssh to login to several boxes and pull their serial number, mac address and IP address.  Everything is working fine except when I write the information to a file.  For some reason, the program is repeating the serial number for each device even though it records to correct IP and MAC address.  A couple lines of output from the script is below.  You notices the serial number is the same even though the IP and MAC are different.  I have over 9k boxes that I need to pull this information from.  Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

ip address,serial number,mac address

10.20.145.245,kamai-19553541,00:03:E6:5F:A4:24

10.36.155.255,kamai-19553541,00:03:E6:5F:AB:68

```
import paramiko
import time
import threading
from queue import Queue

stb_ips = "stb_ip_alive_test.txt"
IP_Addresses_list = []
result = ''
serial_number = ''
hardware_address = ''
ip_address = ''
stb_serial_number_filename = 'stb_serial_numbers.txt'

def stb_serial_number(q):
    global result
    global serial_number
    global hardware_address
    global ip_address
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    try:
        while True:
            name = threading.current_thread().getName()
            # print('Thread', name, q.qsize(), time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
            ip = q.get()
            print('Connecting to ', ip)
            ssh.connect(ip, port=10022, username='xxxx',  
password='xxxx', banner_timeout=70, timeout=70)
            stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('cat /tmp/hostname\n')
            stb_serial_numbers = stdout
            # print(serial_number)
            with open(stb_serial_number_filename, 'w') as f_index:
                f_index.write('ip_address,serial_number,hardware_address\n')
            for line in stb_serial_numbers.readlines():
                serial_number = line.strip()
            stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('/sbin/ifconfig 
eth0\n')
            mac_addresses = stdout
            for mac_address in mac_addresses.readlines():
                if mac_address.startswith('eth0'):
                    tmp = mac_address.split()
                    hardware_address = tmp[4]
                if 'inet' in mac_address:
                    tmp = mac_address.split()
                    ip_address = tmp[1].lstrip('addr:')
                    result += (ip_address + ',' + serial_number + ',' + 
hardware_address + '\n')
            with open(stb_serial_number_filename, 'a') as f:
                f.write(result)
            q.task_done()
    except (TimeoutError, ConnectionResetError, paramiko.SSHException):
        with open('STB_Log_File_' + time.strftime('%m%d%Y%M%S') + '.txt', 
'a') as file_index:
            file_index.write("Error, Connection Timed out or forcibly closed 
while trying to connect to " + ip + '\n')
            ssh.close()

def queue_input(q):
    with open(stb_ips, 'r') as f:
        Ip_Addresses = f.read().splitlines()
    for ip in Ip_Addresses:
        name = threading.current_thread().getName()
        # print('Thread', name, q.qsize(), time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
        q.put(ip)
    q.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue(maxsize=5)
    thread_count = 5
    for i in range(thread_count):
        t = threading.Thread(name='Consumer', target=stb_serial_number, 
args=(q,), daemon=True)
        t.start()
    t = threading.Thread(name='Producer', target=queue_input, args=(q,))
    t.start()
    q.join()
```

Comment: Have you manually checked the serial numbers of 10.20.145.245 and 10.36.155.255? Is at least one of them correct? Have you tried using just one thread?

Comment: Yes, I've checked the.  One of them will be correct.  I was just looking at the threading and yes, if I only use a single thread it works.  So I am sure that's the issue, I'm just not sure how to fix it.  Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`serial_number` has only one value when you go through your `mac_addresses` for loop: the last value you set it to in the other for loop. You're going to need to capture all the lines in that loop, with something like `serial_numbers = [line.strip() for line in stb_serial_numbers]` instead of the first for loop, then make your second loop `for serial_number, mac_address in zip(serial_numbers, mac_addresses):`.

On another note: you're likely to get messed up output sometimes running this  code, because you're writing to the same file from different threads. And similarly, accessing globals from threads is a bad idea. Instead, use a queue to return each thread's results to the main thread and combine them there.

Comment: Thank you Nathan.  I am very new to threading and queues.  Could you give me an example of what you mean by using a queue to return each threads results to the main thread?

Comment: I don't have a fleshed out example handy, but the gist of it is that you would create a second Queue object, maybe called outq, and pass that into the consumer threads. Instead of appending their results to the global result string here `result += (ip_address + ',' + serial_number + ',' + 
hardware_address + '\n')` they would use outq.put to send each result back to the main thread. And then in the main thread, instead of `q.join()` you would read results from the output queue and process them there.